# How can I use all vertical spacing in a Chapter page?

Tags: formatting, chapters, minitoc, renewcommand

A while ago I found a way to format the contents of a Chapter page.  However, I haven't found a way to use all of the page space for the `minitoc` and Chapter Title altogether.

Here's a portion of what I have in my preamble:

```
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}
    {\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\usepackage[headings]{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]
    {\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
```

Currently, the Chapter title appears almost at the vertical middle of the page.  I would like it to appear at the top so as to have more vertical space for the `minitoc`.

Comment: Since you are apparently using titlesec, try using \titlespacing (page 8).

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo, that point me in the right direction.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP solved it himself (as can be seen in his answer without marking it properly).

Comment: @StefanPinnow that doesn't seem to be a valid close reason, especially since there is a 'real' answer (as opposed to an answer posted as comment). The question and answer are not particularly clear (no MWE) but that is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{*3}` right after the `\titleformat` command, like so:

```
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}
    {\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{*3}
\usepackage[headings]{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]
    {\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
```